# Get "PhysicalDriveXXXX" where Windows is installed in C/C++

Tags: c, windows

I always thought that "PhysicalDrive0" was the one where Windows is installed, but it's not!

```
CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", 
      0, 
      FILE_SHARE_READ
      NULL, 
      OPEN_EXISTING,  
      0, 
     NULL);
```

How can I get the "xxxx" number for \\.\PhysicalDrivexxxx programatically in C where Windows is installed?

Comment: you can open `"\\Device\\SystemPartition"` ( if use `CreateFileW` - `"\\\\?\\globalroot\\Device\\SystemPartition"` ) and then `DeviceIoControl` with `IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER` - with this you get disk number

Comment: It seems to work fine on different computers that I tried. Thanks a lot! Probably this should be marked as an answer to my question